# Postgres: Install a specific version of plv8

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I'm installing plv8 in docker:

```
FROM postgres:13 AS build

ENV PLV8_VERSION=v3.0.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y git curl glib2.0 libc++-dev python python3-pip 
       libv8-dev postgresql-server-dev-$PG_MAJOR libncurses5

RUN pip install pgxnclient
RUN pgxn install plv8
```

This still seems to install the `2.3.11` version of plv8 though, which is incompatible with Postgres 13.

Is there any way I can specify the version that `pgxn` installs? Or any other way I can install a Postgres 13 version of plv8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use our finished [docker-images with postgres and plv8](https://hub.docker.com/r/sibedge/postgres-plv8). It's free, images for PostgreSQL 16, PostgreSQL 15, PostgreSQL 14 and PostgreSQL 13 based on Debian and Alpine are available, amd64 and arm64 (with Apple silicon M1/M2/M3 support) architectures maintaned.

```
docker pull sibedge/postgres-plv8
```

Default uses Alpine and last Postgres version. All available tags [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/sibedge/postgres-plv8/tags)

Pay attention, that BigInt is not serializable in v8 and [by default in plv8 v3.0.0 and higher BigInt numbers are converted into string(!)](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/485). But if you need BigInt as numbers support, use this image with Postgres and specific version of plv8:

```
docker pull sibedge/postgres-plv8-bigint
```

OR you can use our binaries with these Dockerfiles and fast build compact images with postgres and plv8 yourself:

[Postgres 14.2, plv8 v3.0.0](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg14-3.0.0-alpine/docker/Dockerfile), Alpine based. size of image is 235MB.

[Postgres 13.6, plv8 v3.0.0](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg13-3.0.0-alpine/docker/Dockerfile), Alpine based. size of image is 231MB.

[Postgres 13.4, plv8 v2.13.15](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg13-2.3.15/docker/Dockerfile), Debian based. size of image is 351MB.

[Postgres 13.6, plv8 v3.0.0](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg13-3.0.0-debian/docker/Dockerfile), Debian based. size of image is 427MB.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build.git
$ cd plv8-build/docker
$ docker build -t pg14-plv8-3
$ docker run -it -d --name pg14-plv8-3 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p 5432:5432/tcp pg14-plv8-3
```

You can use it right now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the latest versions of `plv8` are not yet published on `pgxn` network yet. The [last published version](https://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/) is `2.3.11` and that is what you see here.

To install the latest version of plv8 you can update your `Dockerfile` to build `plv8` from source by following the [build instructions](https://plv8.github.io/#building). A good starting point would be to refer to the docker image [clkao/postgres-plv8](https://github.com/clkao/docker-postgres-plv8/blob/master/10-2/Dockerfile) which was built with `postgres:10` base image.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `bitnami/postgresql` version 14, it's really easy to install plv8 version `2.3.15` by producing the new postgresql image. Here’s how you would normally use in Docker file:

```
FROM bitnami/postgresql:14.9.0-debian-11-r27

ENV PLV8_VERSION=2.3.15

USER root

RUN buildDependencies="build-essential \
      curl \
      wget \
      git-core \
      python \
      python3 \
      gpp \
      cpp \
      pkg-config \
      apt-transport-https \
      cmake \
      libc++-dev \
      libc++abi-dev" \
    && runtimeDependencies="libc++1 \
      libtinfo5 \
      libc++abi1" \
  && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ${buildDependencies} ${runtimeDependencies} \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/build \
    && wget -P /tmp/build/ "https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v${PLV8_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/build/v$PLV8_VERSION.tar.gz -C /tmp/build/ \
    && cd /tmp/build/plv8-$PLV8_VERSION \
    && make static \
    && make install \
    && strip /opt/bitnami/postgresql/lib/plv8-${PLV8_VERSION}.so \
    && rm -rf /root/.vpython_cipd_cache /.vpython-root \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get remove -y ${buildDependencies} python2.7 \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /tmp/build /var/lib/apt/lists/* \

USER 1001
```